# How to align an input box with an image in a Next.js app

Tags: css, reactjs, input, alignment, next.js

I want to horizontally align the input box with the image on the right along their centers, but the input box is always offset downwards. These elements are in a navigation bar.

I have tried applying CSS properties to the `.leftel` class, including `vertical align: center;` and   changing the `line-height`. However, the output has remained unaffected. I have also tried modifying the padding, border, and margin for input.

This is how it appears: [navigation bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMbZS.png)

In the navigation bar component,

```
<div className="leftel">
  <Link href="/">
    <a><Image src="/logo.png" width={78} height={35}/></a>
  </Link>  
  <input className="searchBar" placeholder="Search here..."/>
</div>
```

This is the CSS for each of the classes:

```
.leftel{
  float: left;
}

.leftel Image, .leftel input{
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.searchBar {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: none;
  width: 600px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: flex-end;
  background-color: #3A4466;
  font-family: "Nunito";
}
```

Comment: have you tried using flex?

Comment: @DannyLyzo I added a `display: flex` property to the leftel class and it worked! Thank you!